# Beam how to force a restart of my application android

Tags: android, refresh, nfc, android-lifecycle, android-beam

I use Beam API to exchange data by NFC.
I need to reinitialize my exchanged data, else the same data are sent when the devices approach from each to other again.
How to force the reinitialization? with a call to onCreate? how to implement

Comment: Somewhere in your code you will get a callback for NFC related interaction. Why not put your reinitialization there?

Comment: how do you implement that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [OnNdefPushCompleteCallback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.OnNdefPushCompleteCallback.html) interface.